# Signature for Doctor of Information Technology prefix and suffix

Tags: names, suffixes, prefixes, signage

How can I sign my name with the degree of "[Doctor of Information Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Information_Technology)"

Is this all correct

**Dr.Full Name**

**Full Name D.I.T**

**Dr Full Name
(Doctor of Information Technology)**

**Dr.Last Name**

Can I use these king of signatures in my emails or letters?

Comment: This is not a PhD. But is equivalent to it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Information_Technology. I want to know if I can use my signature in emails or letters as asked above

Comment: This was cross-posted to [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/10884/signature-for-doctor-of-information-technology-prefix-and-suffix#10884).

Comment: Yes. Shall i delete it from here? I have already mentioned there it is migrated from this to writers

Comment: Except you didn't migrate it, you cross-posted it. In the future you should click the flag button on your question, click the "moderator attention" option, and ask the mods to migrate it.

Comment: @WendiKidd thank you for the info. followed your recommendation

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about signature etiquette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may use any of these:

- **Dr. Full Name**
- **Full Name, DIT**
- **Dr. Lastname**

Note the comma after the full name in the second option.